# static member cannot be used as a default function parameter in PHP5?

Tags: php, parameters, static-members

dose php5 forbid this usage, the following code doesn't work

```
class Foo{
    public static $data = "abcd";
}

function tt($para = Foo::$data)
{
    echo $para;
}

tt ("rcohu");
```

it reports:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in /home/jw/sk/sk.php on line 6

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in /home/jw/sk/sk.php on line 6
```

Comment: if you are happy with my answer, can you mark it as such

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function tt($para = Foo::$data)
{
    echo $para;
}
```

function definitions can only contain simple assignments, not complex ones like Foo::$data.

Just do this:

```
function tt($para = false)
{
    if(!$para) $para = Foo::$data;
    echo $para;
}
```

Comment: They just cannot contain variable expressions. `Foo::DATA` where `DATA` is a class constant works.

Comment: True, so if you had `define('DATA', 'my-data');` you could use `function tt($para=DATA){`